# Convert SimpleXML to JSON PHP

Tags: php, xml, json

I am using Bigbluebutton's PHP API and I want to get all meeting sessions. In calling the method to display the meetings, I get this output:

```
Array (

[returncode] => SimpleXMLElement Object
    (
        [0] => SUCCESS
    )

[messageKey] => SimpleXMLElement Object
    (
    )

[message] => SimpleXMLElement Object
    (
    )

[0] => Array
    (
        [meetingId] => SimpleXMLElement Object
            (
                [0] => as's meeting
            )

        [meetingName] => SimpleXMLElement Object
            (
                [0] => as's meeting
            )

        [createTime] => SimpleXMLElement Object
            (
                [0] => 1380878550574
            )

        [attendeePw] => SimpleXMLElement Object
            (
                [0] => ap
            )

        [moderatorPw] => SimpleXMLElement Object
            (
                [0] => mp
            )

        [hasBeenForciblyEnded] => SimpleXMLElement Object
            (
                [0] => false
            )

        [running] => SimpleXMLElement Object
            (
                [0] => false
            )

    )

[1] => Array
    (
        [meetingId] => SimpleXMLElement Object
            (
                [0] => XYZ's meeting
            )

        [meetingName] => SimpleXMLElement Object
            (
                [0] => XYZ's meeting
            )

        [createTime] => SimpleXMLElement Object
            (
                [0] => 1380879253000
            )

        [attendeePw] => SimpleXMLElement Object
            (
                [0] => ap
            )

        [moderatorPw] => SimpleXMLElement Object
            (
                [0] => mp
            )

        [hasBeenForciblyEnded] => SimpleXMLElement Object
            (
                [0] => false
            )

        [running] => SimpleXMLElement Object
            (
                [0] => true
            )

    )

)
```

How can I turn this simplexml top json?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can use json_encode.
http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php

```
json_encode($array)
```

Comment: Thanks, pretty straight forward.

Comment: I don't know why this answer is upvoted and accepted. It doesnt do a 1-to-1 conversion, as duplicate XML tags will be overwritten.

Comment: This answer is specific to data in the question.

Answer (score 1):

Here is why this is a very bad idea.

```
$xml     = '<root><test><line code="line1">hello</line><line code="line2">world</line></test></root>';
$element = new \SimpleXMLElement($xml);
$json    = json_encode($element);
```

If you look at the output of `json_encode`, it will be as follows:

```
{"test":{"line":["hello","world"]}}
```

You just lost all of your attributes due to having repeated elements. There is no "simple" solution, you have to use a custom piece of code that will cycle through each element and format it properly. If you do try to access the element through `$element`, you can still get the attributes because SimpleXML is not a regular PHP class.

I came up with a solution that will work for the example I gave, and for typical problems, although it does not handle namespaces.

http://pastebin.com/ksSqkJbu